# Checking iOS requestReview() output?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, storekit, skstorereviewcontroller

Is there any way to know if the user tapped a star to rate the app or clicked `Not Now` when `requestReview()` is presented?

I would like to be able to reward the user if he or she rated the app and not call `requestReview()` again in that case.

Thank you!

Comment: I don’t think this is possible. Also, Apple expressly forbid providing an incentive for reviews.

Comment: @Chris Oh I see, thanks!

Comment: Sorry to break the bad news! :)

Comment: Haha don't worry, the lack of information about the subject suggested an answer already :)) I'll find a way!