# Is it possible to see what the user selects on a "rate this app" popup?

Tags: ios, swift, analytics, storekit

I have an ios app that I'm developing, and I am using StoreKit's requestReview() to ask the user to submit a review for the app.  The problem I am running into, and that I can't find an answer about, is related to analytics.  I would like to see what the user selects when the "rate this app" popup appears so I can track how many users choose to rate the app and how many simply dismiss the popup.  But, since I am using Apple's function and not my own component, I don't know if this is possible.

So the short version is this.  Is it possible to get the user's selection on a "rate this app" popup when using requestReview()?  If so, how?

Comment: No. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49980650/checking-ios-requestreview-output

Comment: Great, thank you for linking that thread.